# cdn deploy static files magento - still deploying to "normal" directories

Tags: magento2, static-content, cdn

I'm trying to get my static files to be deployed in static.domain.com

I have pointed my base url and secure base urls like below

[image: admin configuration]

After I did - the website is trying to pull data from that location but when I check the folder of the new subdomain no files are generated after I deployed the static content and cleared all caches. The static content is still deployed in domain.com/pub/static instead of static.domain.com/pub/static.

am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

What is unclear in every documentation and not described is that you have to add a pointer to the directory which is what solved my Problem. I made it work using symlinks